# How to get the value from button

Tags: silverlight, button, listbox, windows-phone-7.1

I have implemented a listbox with buttons as follows

```
                        <Button.Content>

                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="440" Height="210">
                                <Image Source="{Binding Image}"  Height="120" Width="120"/>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Height="200">
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="40">
                                        <TextBlock Width="100" Text="TITLE" Height="40" FontSize="22"/>
                                        <TextBlock Width="220" Text="{Binding Title}" Height="40" FontSize="22"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="40">
                                        <TextBlock Width="100" Text="Detail" Height="40" FontSize="22"/>
                                        <TextBlock Width="220" Text="{Binding description}" Height="40" FontSize="22"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="40">
                                        <TextBlock Width="100" Text="Discount" Height="40" FontSize="22"/>
                                        <TextBlock Width="220" Text="{Binding discount}" Height="40" FontSize="22"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="40" >
                                        <TextBlock Width="100" Text="Deal ID" Height="40" FontSize="22"/>
                                        <TextBlock Name="dealID" Width="220" Text="{Binding DID}" Height="40" FontSize="22"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </StackPanel>                                 

                            </StackPanel>
                        </Button.Content>
                    </Button>

                </DataTemplate>         
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

Now the problem that i face is when i click the button i want to get the value of dealID thats in the last text block binded to DID. For this i created the event handler for button click as follows

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button myButton = sender as Button;

    }
```

Now i dont have any clue what to do next the mybutton.content method is not working for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use Blend for that, you can declare click event on xaml, its more easy.

Comment: as said.. click event is there.. i have the arguments and the objects.. but not that 'specific' value

Comment: @learner_17 you can google it there is tons of tuttorial on web

Comment: it worked... thanks..hit and trial :p used tag="{binding DID}"

Answer (score 0):

u might want to cast the mybutton.content to the template that you have written inside the content i.e. to a stackpanel..

Comment: it sounds good but in that case the next items in list box do not get arranged as properly..

Comment: my guess is you want the values of the textblocks inside the stack panel..you could also loop through the childcontrols in the stackpanel to get the values. ...I am still not sure what you mean by "the next items in list box do not get arranged as properly"

Comment: yes exactly... i want the value from textblocks. by "the next items in list box do not get arranged as properly" i mean that i want every new listbox item to be a new button and thats why this doesnt work(mybutton.content to stackpanel

Comment: and adding content on a textblock gives attachable property not found error